# how to add value into firebase field

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native

I'm new to react native and firebase, and trying to create a social media app, building up a adding friend feature.

I'm trying to add UID into the current user's database
here is my code :

```
    const friendadd = async() =>{

        
       // get the users field
        const friendlist = firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("UID", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get();

        const addfriend = await friendlist.update({
            "FriendsList.yVHnHIqhsOYbVbWOM6TbjpU4N3x1":true
        })

        
    }
    friendadd()


}
```

and this is what my firebase looks like [image: Firebase]

by using the code above, it doesn't update the field somehow. but if I hard code the doc it will work :

```
const friendlist = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('CgQklWWClMJdoOvU4pEk')
```

how do I get the current user and update the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an entry to your `FriendsList` field, you can [use an `arrayUnion` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
friendlist.update({
  FriendsList: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
    uid: "uidOfItemToAdd",
    bio: "bioOfItemToAdd"
  })
});
```

---

**Update**:
This code sets `friendlist` to  a `Promise<QuerySnapshot>`:

```
const friendlist = firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("UID", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get();
```

To process these documents and update each of them:

```
friendlist.then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.ref.update(...); //  here goes the same code as above
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, I tried this way, but still didn't update. I'm wondering if its because `const friendlist = firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("UID", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get();` this line? it didn't get into the doc?

Comment: Because if i hard code the .doc, it will update. `const friendlist = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('CgQklWWClMJdoOvU4pEk')`. how do i get the current document?

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. I updated the code in my answer, but strongly recommend spending some time in the documentation on processing queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query, or in the codelab: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web

Comment: Thank you so much.  for the update, is there a way to locate other people's uid? and add it to current users FriendsList?